# Transferring certain cells from one sheet to another in excel despite column/row insertion/extraction

Tags: excel

The title pretty much says it. I need to transfer certain cells from one cell to another without the coordinates of the cells changing after an insert operation.

In ex., I want the value of cell B3 of Sheet1 to transfer to cell A2 of Sheet2. If I insert a column on the left of B3, the previous B3 will become C3 and you now have a new B3 in which you can add a new value. I want my A2 to still receive the value of B3, but the new B3, not the old B3 with is now C3.

If I go with `+Sheet1!B3`, after the insertion of the column it will become `+Sheet1!C3`. I want it to remain to `+Sheet1!B3`.

I tried with $, +Sheet1!$B$3, but it still changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the indirect function in excel.

```
+INDIRECT("Sheet1!B3")
```

Comment: not a wrong answer as it will work.  Depending on how many cells its being applied to it may not be the best solution as it is a volatile function and will cause each formula to recalculate anytime something in the workbook changes.  over a small number of cells not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

With the caveat that you never change the location of column A you could do the following:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$$ZZ,ROW(B3),2)
```

Caveat:  as set up will only work for cells between and including columns A and ZZ.  the ZZ reference will increase as columns get added.  If you have columns outside of ZZ initially, then you will have to adjust the final column reference to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

INDEX gave me some errors in the function (probably on my end), but I managed to solve it using INDIRECT.
Ty for the feedback, @AlexCollins @ForwardEd